# Browse PDF file from iPhone and Upload on server

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, file-upload

In my application I need to allow the user to browse some PDF files from iPhone and upload one to a server.
I know how to upload a PDF file on a server, but I don't know how can I browse for PDF files.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can only view files in that your App's sandbox. Every App has got a Documents, Cache and temp folders.

sample code :

```
NSError *err        = nil;
NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *myPath    = [myPathList  objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *dirContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:myPath error:&err];
if(err) NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",[err localizedDescription]);
NSMutableArray *filePaths  = nil;

int count = (int)[dirContent count];
for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    [filePaths addObject:[dirContent objectAtIndex:i]];
}
return filePaths;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I want to browse PDf file and allow user to select and upload. I've implemented for image but i didn't find any solution for PDf file.

Comment: As i mentioned you can ONLY access the files from your App's Sandbox. There is no way to list the pdf like you did for the images from iPhone gallery.